# ¿Como mandar variable o valor a otro metodo?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Visual Studio 2017, en C#, quisiera saber como puedo mandar el valor de la variable

```
public static DialogResult BandaOption(string title, string promText, ref string value, int tipo)
    {
        Form frm = new Form();
        Label label = new Label();
        System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox combo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        Button buttonOK = new Button();
        Button buttonCancel = new Button();

        frm.Text = title;
        label.Text = promText;
        combo.Text = value;
        combo.Items.Add("Banda 1");
        combo.Items.Add("Banda 2");

        buttonOK.Text = "Aceptar";
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancelar";
        buttonOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;           

        label.AutoSize = true;
        combo.Anchor = combo.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonOK.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        frm.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
        frm.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, combo, buttonOK, buttonCancel });
        frm.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), frm.ClientSize.Height);
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        frm.MinimizeBox = false;
        frm.MaximizeBox = false;
        frm.AcceptButton = buttonOK;
        frm.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

        DialogResult dialog = frm.ShowDialog();
        value = Convert.ToString(combo.SelectedItem); //--> el valor de esta variable
        return dialog;
    }
```

a otro método dentro del mismo windows forms, para poder guardar unos datos.
Ya lo he intentado con otros códigos, pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ver si entendi tu problema, tienes un WinForms el cual tiene 2 metodos `BandaOption` y el metodo donde quieres recibir el valor de la variable, ejemplo `MetodoRecepcionParametro` y quieres utilizar el valor de la variable `value` dentro del segundo metodo. Si es asi, puedes hacerlo muy sencillo utilizando una variable global. Ejemplo:

```
        static string valorGlobal; //Variable global declaracion

    public static DialogResult BandaOption(string title, string promText, ref string value, int tipo)
    {
        Form frm = new Form();
        Label label = new Label();
        System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox combo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        Button buttonOK = new Button();
        Button buttonCancel = new Button();

        frm.Text = title;
        label.Text = promText;
        combo.Text = value;
        combo.Items.Add("Banda 1");
        combo.Items.Add("Banda 2");

        buttonOK.Text = "Aceptar";
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancelar";
        buttonOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        label.AutoSize = true;
        combo.Anchor = combo.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonOK.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        frm.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
        frm.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, combo, buttonOK, buttonCancel });
        frm.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), frm.ClientSize.Height);
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        frm.MinimizeBox = false;
        frm.MaximizeBox = false;
        frm.AcceptButton = buttonOK;
        frm.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

        DialogResult dialog = frm.ShowDialog();
        value = Convert.ToString(combo.SelectedItem); //--> el valor de esta variable
        valorGlobal = value;  //Se asigna a la variable global
        return dialog;
    }

    public void Metodo2() {
        //Usar variable global 
        var valor = valorGlobal;
    }
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: si, de hecho lo resolví así, de todos modos gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

la clase Form contiene una propiedad Tag de tipo object donde puedes asignarle cualquier objeto

```c#
frm.Tag = combo.SelectedItem;
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8